# Intellij produces unit test log output files in /tmp/idea_test_*.out, prefixed by NORMAL_OUTPUT

Tags: intellij-idea

Whenever a run a unit test in Intellij (`org.junit.Test`), a file of the form `/tmp/idea_test_*.out` is produced containing some log output that looks similar to log entries that are produced by the tests but seeming with each line prefixed by "`NORMAL_OUTPUT`". I've grepped the codebase and it seems that neither the string "NORMAL_OUTPUT", nor the string "idea_test" is present in the repository, though I suspect some plugin or setting that I can't yet find. Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this?

I checked the log output location specified in `Run/Debug Configurations > Logs > Save console output to file`. This setting is not set.

Comment: Why exactly is that a problem that running a test in IntelliJ IDEA creates a temporary file in the temp directory?

Comment: It can fill it up.

Answer (score 0):

These files are created by [this code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/testRunner/src/com/intellij/execution/testframework/CompositePrintable.java#L176) and are normally deleted automatically [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/testRunner/src/com/intellij/execution/testframework/CompositePrintable.java#L191). This is entirely part of IntelliJ IDEA's normal functioning; it is not controlled by any setting or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the tmp files is governed by the JVM system property `java.io.tmpdir`. I found that adding this to the `bin/idea.properties` file had no effect on my installation, so I just edited the startup script to add the property, e.g.

`-Djava.io.tmpdir=/alternative_tmp_dir`