# How to prevent idea test output files when running JUnit Tests in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I'm running my unit tests right now (they are very intensive, lots out console output and run for a long time)... I noticed that my disk space was disappearing.

Turns out there are a few files being created

[image]

I'm not really sure what is causing this: IntelliJ, the IntelliJ Junit plugin or the console somehow. I don't think it is the console because after I noticed this problem, I installed a different console and the problem still occurs. I googled but couldn't find information about these files.

Anyone know how I can disable this?

Comment: Do you have "Save console output to file" option on at Run/Debug configuration https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-junit.html ?

Comment: no, it looks like I have the exact same problem as over here: [Intellij produces unit test log output files in /tmp/idea_test_*.out, prefixed by NORMAL_OUTPUT - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087462/intellij-produces-unit-test-log-output-files-in-tmp-idea-test-out-prefixed-b) - however, no solution was offered there either (just an explanation of sorts)

Comment: i think there is a bug in my code making it run so long (even though it is a long test), because I migrated this "old" project over to a new machine and haven't run it in a year - but still, the problem is I would like to let it run a bit longer but my hard drive fills up pretty fast since I only have 18gb free before running the tests